# Coffeescript cant access to other js files

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, referenceerror

I am compiling two different projects with coffeescript compiler. In each project are different classes and if I try to access to the others projects class the browser will call me "Reference Error" xyz is not defined.

Things I did:
- I checked my sourcecode if there were any syntax errors or logical errors
- I checked my sourcecode if the class is really existing -> yes it is
- I checked my js files if they are in the right way bound into the html document -> yes they are.

Kind regards

Comment: Did you check the js files are loading in the correct order? That has caught me out a couple of times.

Comment: i already checked it. the order is correct

Comment: Can you access them in the browser console

Comment: I found a fix with global classes: http://justinreid.com/coffeescript-global-classes/